# How can I calculate Helmholtz chamber dimensions?

Tags: acoustics, frequency

I'd like to do the calculations on this page manually [Cavity Resonant Frequency](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Waves/cavity.html#c4)  as I'm entering in values and the results are outside of what I expect, so I'm hoping to learn the manual way of calculating it first to teach me how to use the calculator properly.

Does the speed of sound always have to be meters per second? Can the area be in square inches?

Here are some values I've calculated and the results ... do my calculations appear correct?

```
125hz

160 inches of volume with a 8" long 1.5" u bend
128 inches of volume with a 10" long 1.5" u bend
107 inches of volume with a 12" long 1.5" u bend

163hz
94 inches of volume with a 8" long 1.5" u bend
76 inches of volume with a 10" long 1.5" u bend
63 inches of volume with a 12" long 1.5" u bend

200hz
63" of volume with a 8" long 1.5" u bend
50" of volume with a 10" long 1.5" u bend
42" of volume with a 12" long 1.5" u bend


63hz

632 inches of volume with a 8" long 1.5" u bend
505 inches of volume with a 10" long 1.5" u bend
421 inches of volume with a 12" long 1.5" u bend

82hz
373 inches of volume with a 8" long 1.5" u bend
298 inches of volume with a 10" long 1.5" u bend
249 inches of volume with a 12" long 1.5" u bend

100hz
250" of volume with a 8" long 1.5" u bend
201" of volume with a 10" long 1.5" u bend
167" of volume with a 12" long 1.5" u bend
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that comes upon this later

> F = (SoS/2pi) * √(A / VL)
>
> V = A / (L(F/(SoS/2pi)))^2
>
> L = A / (V(F/(SoS/2pi)))^2
>
> (VL) * (F/(SoS/2pi))^2 = A

Excel

> C5 = area, C4 = length, C7 = frequency, C6 = The speed of sound
>
> V=SUM(C5/(C4*(C7/(C6/(2*(22/7))))^2))
>
> D5 = area, D3 = area, D7 = frequency, D6 = The speed of sound
>
> L=SUM(D5/(D3*(D7/(D6/(2*(22/7))))^2))
>
> E3 = area, E4 = length, E7 = frequency, E6 = The speed of sound
>
> A=SUM(E3*E4) * (E7/(E6/(2*(22/7))))^2